# Arduino input fluctuates

Tags: arduino

With the following code I get a log like the one below. Why is that?

```
int analogPin = 5;
int val = 0;

void setup(void) {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
   val = analogRead(analogPin);
   Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
   Serial.println(val);   
}
```

Result:

```
Analog reading = 998
Analog reading = 981
Analog reading = 511
Analog reading = 159
Analog reading = 24
Analog reading = 108
Analog reading = 439
Analog reading = 946
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 420
Analog reading = 116
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 151
Analog reading = 542
Analog reading = 997
Analog reading = 982
Analog reading = 513
Analog reading = 161
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 107
Analog reading = 437
Analog reading = 945
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 421
Analog reading = 117
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 150
Analog reading = 541
Analog reading = 997
Analog reading = 983
Analog reading = 515
Analog reading = 162
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 107
Analog reading = 437
Analog reading = 945
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 422
Analog reading = 117
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 149
Analog reading = 540
Analog reading = 997
Analog reading = 983
Analog reading = 516
Analog reading = 162
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 107
Analog reading = 436
Analog reading = 945
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 422
Analog reading = 117
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 150
Analog reading = 540
Analog reading = 998
Analog reading = 982
Analog reading = 516
Analog reading = 162
Analog reading = 25
Analog reading = 108
Analog reading = 437
```

Is the result just noise?

And as soon as I plug in a cable I see the following pattern:

```
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 72
Analog reading = 447
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 118
Analog reading = 849
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 835
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 40
Analog reading = 401
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 0
Analog reading = 89
Analog reading = 475
Analog reading = 1023
Analog reading = 1023
```

Is that my heartbeat or so??? No idea what can have such an influence on a empty pin.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's quite normal for an unconnected analog pin to produce random noise. From the [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/random) (emphasis mine):

> If it is important for a sequence of values generated by `random()` to differ, on subsequent executions of a sketch, use `randomSeed()` to initialize the random number generator with a **fairly random input, such as analogRead() on an unconnected pin.**

With regards to the values that you see when you plug in the cable, whether or not they make sense depends on the signal that you feed into the pin. If there's some discrepancy, it might be worth looking at the signal with an oscilloscope.

Also, see [How come analogRead reads oscillating values from 0 to 1023 when no actual input is present?](http://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/rtylu/how_come_analogread_reads_oscillating_values_from/)

Answer (score 1):

Its a floating input. if a pin its not connected to anything or directly connected to a 5V source.
The arduino [Button tutorial](http://arduino.cc/it/Tutorial/Button) explains this a bit.
For more details look at the wikipedia [Pull-up Resistor page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor)

Answer (score 0):

I have PPG sensor board and Arduino Mega. I tried your code on my kit. When PPG sensor board detect my heart rate it begin to change all zeros. Let me explain the serial monitor output. Firstly everywhere is 0. My heart rate is detected. It is not 0 now. It is full of numbers instead. These are not noise only. These are noise+real heart rate numbers for me now. Arduino shows graphical peaks at its detection frequency, I guess.